# Unable to update a field in phpMyadmin using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to update a field in database using php, everytime I run the script there is no effect on the table. Here's how my code looks :

```
$sql="UPDATE users set sentMsg = $msg+1 where username = '$username' ";
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

where $link is the connection variable which is working fine with other queries.
Here's the table structure.
[image]

The $result variable is returning true.
I am unable to understand where the actual problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and see about sql injection, and the vital importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: what is the actual value of $msg ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try this

```
$sql="UPDATE `users` SET `sentMsg` =".($msg+1)." WHERE `username` ='".$username."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

Thats what i could make out of your code till now.

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
$newCount = $msg+1;

$sql="UPDATE users set sentMsg = $newCount where username = '$username' ";
$result = $link->query($sql);
```

or

```
$sql="UPDATE users set sentMsg = ".($msg + 1)." where username = '$username' ";
$result = $link->query($sql);
```